# Spring @Scheduled cron details from property file - Exception

Tags: spring, cron, properties-file, spring-scheduled

I was trying to define the cron details in my spring @Scheduled method

```
@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class CacheRefreshService {

@Scheduled(cron = "${api.refresh.cron}")
     public void refreshJob() throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Started Refresh");
        //do something
     }
}
```

And in my application.properties

```
#Refresh
api.refresh.cron =0 29 11 * * ?
```

When I define the cron details along with @Scheduled, it is running fine. But when I do this, it is not able to read the value from the properties file and the below error is thrown.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'refreshJob': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "${api.refresh.cron}")
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your `@PropertySource` should go on an `@Configuration` class not a `@Service` class. Also your code doesn't seem to match the error you get, so which is it...

Comment: @M.Deinum This is a service class. So how do I read the property here? Have updated the error message

Comment: The use of the property (`@Value`) is something different then reading the file. Your `@PropertySource` is now pretty much useless as it doesn't do anything. Also you need to register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to have things replaced.

Comment: @M.Deinum It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding the below to my ApplicationContext resolved the issue..

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
       return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
factoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *");
```

you have to set Cron Expresssion bcz in `BeanFactory` Class the `setCronExpression` is mandatory