# Spring: How to provide a specific property file in the @Scheduled annotation?

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

Normally, we can use a cron expression defined as "`cron.expression`" in the default property file, as follows:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
public void demoServiceMethod(){

}
```

But I wish to define a property file for this class itself, and use the "`cron.expression`" property from this file. How can I do that?

P.S: I am using Java 1.7

Comment: `I wish to define a property file for this class itself` What do you mean by **this class**? Please share some example how your desired code should look

Comment: By **this class**, I mean that that while using @Value annotation in this class, properties should be picked up from this new property file, and everywhere else, the usual property sources should be used

Comment: is following format acceptable for you? `@Scheduled(cron = "file.properties:${cron.expression}")`

Comment: It didn't recognize the key `cron.expression` present in `file.properties` (which is placed at the classpath and is already beign picked up if we use `MessageBundle`). I als tried : `@Scheduled(cron = "classpath:file.properties:${cron.expression}")` and it didn't work either.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to work :) I just asked if that format would be OK for you to use

Answer (score 0):

Add to your class [PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html)

```
 @PropertySource("classpath:other.properties")
```

Or [using Configuration](https://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/how-to-propertysource-annotations-in.html?m=1)

> ```
>  @Configuration
>  @PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:/datasource.properties")})
> ```

Comment: According to the link you provided, *@PropertySource* can only be used in conjunction with *@Configuration*. As such, it would apply this setting to the entire application. I only want it to be applicable to this class

Comment: @daud see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195290/spring-scheduled-cron-details-from-property-file-exception

Comment: According to the above link, a **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** needs to be configured. But that again would set it for the entire application. I need properties to be picked up from a different property file, *only* for this specific class